# TabHost in FragmentActivity and screen rotation

Tags: java, android

I don't understand how to use retain instance on a screen rotation while I am using a TabHost inside a FragmentActivity. I found a lot of things about that, but either talking about to use onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() which is deprecated. Or tu use  setRetainInstance(boolean) but FragmentActivity doesn't have this method. Only Fragment have it.

On this link you can find out the code of my main activity:
http://code.google.com/p/musclehackandroid/source/browse/src/com/musclehack/musclehack/MainActivity.java

Thanks in advance,

Cédric

Answer (score 0):

You can use onSavedInstanceState to save the current selected tab:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("TAB_POSITION", host.getCurrentTab());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Afterwards you can retrain the selected position in onCreate:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    host.setCurrentTab(savedInstanceState.getInt("TAB_POSITION"));
}
```

Comment: Ok this works but it destroys and recreate every fragment each time. I just have a question. Is there an automatic way to handle the fact that in my fragment, I do a lot of (navigation through ListFragment) fragment transaction:
  FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

  transaction.replace(this.getId(), newFragment);
  transaction.addToBackStack(null);

  transaction.commit();
Or do I have to keep track of the current transaction and handle it manually?

Comment: I think the easiest way to do this, is to just keep track of your active fragments. Are these fragments you navigate to all different fragments or the same fragments with other content?

Comment: Now I keep track of the current fragment level (I can navigate through 4 ListFragment. I have that code in my onCreate method of the main activity:   int levelChoice = WorkoutManagerSingleton.getInstance().getLevelChoice();
  if(levelChoice == 0){
   this.fragment2worklog = new Fragment2worklog();
  }else if(levelChoice == 1){
   this.fragment2worklog = new Fragment2worklog_1subProg();
  }else if(levelChoice == 2){
   this.fragment2worklog = new Fragment2worklog_2week();
  }else if(levelChoice == 3){
   ...

Comment: But with that code, the undo doesn't  work. The fragment created that way is not destroyed doing an undo after a rotation and thus I see 2 FragmentList at the same time.

Comment: Can you post some code please? Then I might be able to situate the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Well my application is about 5000 lines of code that's why I put the google code git repositery. But I found out a solution!
First, while creating my activity, I check if I was on the tab area I have issue with. If yes I remove all transaction inforamtion.

```
if(savedInstanceState != null){
                        int tabPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("TAB_POSITION");
                        if(tabPosition == 1){
                                FragmentManager manager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
                                for(int i = 0; i < manager.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {    
                                        manager.popBackStack();
                                }
                        }
                }
```

Then, here is how I reload all of the fragment registering again the previous corumpted transitions.

```
TabHost.OnTabChangeListener listener = new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                Log.d("MainActivity","public void onTabChanged(String tabId) { called");
                if(tabId.equals(TAB_A)){
                        pushFragments(getString(R.string.rss), fragment1rss);
                }else if(tabId.equals(TAB_B)){
                        pushFragments(getString(R.string.worklog), fragment2worklog);
                        int levelChoice = WorkoutManagerSingleton.getInstance().getLevelChoice();
                        ListFragment nextFragment = null;
                        if(levelChoice > 0){
                                nextFragment = new Fragment2worklog_1subProg();
                                pushFragmentsRegisterInStack(nextFragment);
                        }
                        if(levelChoice > 1){
                                nextFragment = new Fragment2worklog_2week();
                                pushFragmentsRegisterInStack(nextFragment);
                        }
                        if(levelChoice > 2){
                                nextFragment = new Fragment2worklog_3day();
                                pushFragmentsRegisterInStack(nextFragment);
                        }
                        if(levelChoice > 3){
                                nextFragment = new Fragment2worklog_4exercices();
                                pushFragmentsRegisterInStack(nextFragment);
                        }
                }else if(tabId.equals(TAB_C)){
                        pushFragments(getString(R.string.testimonials), fragment3testimonials);
                }else if(tabId.equals(TAB_D)){
                        pushFragments(getString(R.string.recipes), fragment4recipe);
                }else if(tabId.equals(TAB_E)){
                        pushFragments(getString(R.string.archives), fragment5archives);
                }else if(tabId.equals(TAB_F)){
                        pushFragments(getString(R.string.book), fragment6book);
                }
                Log.d("MainActivity","public void onTabChanged(String tabId) { end");
        }
};

/*
 * adds the fragment to the FrameLayout
 */
public void pushFragments(String tag, Fragment fragment){
        FragmentManager manager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, fragment);
        ft.commit();
}

public void pushFragmentsRegisterInStack(Fragment fragment){
        FragmentManager manager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
}
```